# Best way to debug 'Can't set headers after they are sent' error in Express / Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to debug the dreaded `Can't set headers after they are sent` error in a node.js Express application. Specifically, I'm using the [knox](https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox) library to talk to s3.

Roughly, I have this Express handler, using a global instance of a knox s3client:

```
function foo(req, res) {
    //Region A
    var s3req = global.s3client.get('foo').on('response', function(s3res){
        //Region B
        res.set('content-length', s3res.headers['content-length']); //This will fail
        s3res.on('data', function(chunk){
            res.write(chunk);
        });
    });
    //Region C
    s3req.end();
}
```

If I set any header or status code on `res` in Region A, everything works fine. If I try any of that in Region B, I get the "Can't set headers after they are sent" error. Note that I want to set headers on `res`, not `s3res`

Presumably `response.writeHead` is being called or triggered somewhere before the on response callback of the knox s3client is being called. Is there some debug flag or other way to get Node to spit out when/where writeHead has been called? Node 0.10 adds a `response.headersSent`, but it would be prohibitively hard to fill my code and all 3rd party libraries with a check of this flag to figure out where this is getting called. Or is there someway else to figure out this problem?

Comment: I encounter this sometime ago. can I suggest to try a different version of express first, meaning upgrade or downgrade your express.js.

Comment: I've tried both Express 3.1 and 3.2.1. I've also tried node 0.10.3 and node 0.10.5

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try to include a simple middleware that dumps a stack trace to stdout when `writeHead` is called:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.on('header', function() {
    console.trace('HEADERS GOING TO BE WRITTEN');
  });
  next();
});
```

You have to insert that before routes/middleware that might trigger your problem.

FWIW, my guess would be that the problem is triggered by something happening in region C (either a `res.send`, `res.end`, `res.json` or `res.render` that's being called there):

```
function foo(req, res) {
    //Region A
    var s3req = global.s3client.get('foo').on('response', function(s3res){
        //Region B
        res.set('content-length', s3res.headers['content-length']);
    }); 
    //Region C
}
```

**EDIT** if `s3res` is a proper stream, you can try this:

```
function foo(req, res) {
  global.s3client.get('foo').on('response', function(s3res) {
    s3res.pipe(res);
  }).end();
}
```

But be aware that *all* headers returned by the S3 request will be passed to the Express response.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I edited question with more details. Indeed am calling s3req.end() in Region C (see updated question). But removing it gives `Error: socket hang up`. If I just want to stream s3res back to foo's res, and set content-type as well as content-length headers, what is the best solution here?

Comment: `s3req.end()` shouldn't be the problem, that's not part of Express. I guess it depends on the context in which you call `foo()`, although (as @wayne already suggested) I also seem to remember some issues with Node that would generate this problem for no apparent reason.

Comment: foo is just one of my api's methods, registered as an express get handler. The high level purpose of the method is to return the contents of a private s3 bucket (as an aside, I realize I can use expiring signed S3 urls for this. But for now I need to retain backwards compatibility to before I used s3). Is there an easier way to proxy/attach the s3res back to res (the response seen by the caller of the API method)? Doing this "manually" as I'm doing is error-prone, as you see.

Comment: See my edit. Not sure if it's going to work, but worth a try :)

Comment: Marked as accepted. All your advice held true. The "middleware" you suggested to log writehead worked, and pointed to a spot in my code that was calling end() on the stream in a supposed error case. It was "effectively" in region C  as you suspected (although in reality a bit more complicated since I simplified the code). Your pipe advice was also valuable, I was even able to set my own headers before calling pipe to pipe s3res to res, which show up in the actual response. So all is good again - thanks much!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if it applies here, but what I immediately thought of when seeing the error, was a simple very simple mistake in "callback-logic" somewhere in the "model layer". I had been head scratching over this in two separate instances, in both instances it turned out to be that I called a callback (i.e. one that eventually would call the response-writing callback) twice. This would happen only on an error in my model layer, because it was code like:

```
if (err) cb(err) // note the missing "return" here
cb(null,result) // alternatively, also no "else"
```

If I were to run into such an error now, the first thing I do would be to check if the response-writing callback is called twice for any operation. Simply two `console.log` statements one in region A (the scope where the Knox request is initiated) and one in region C (the response-writing callback) would suffice for at least eliminating this possibility.

In principle, your `res` object should be pretty protected. Only connect / express middleware has access to it, and this particular request handler of course. So there are only a limited number of places that have the power of having a header being written.

Comment: I just had the same issue, it was obviously more complicated than that but that's pretty much what happened!

Comment: True, later versions of express seem to be less tolerant of exactly that error.