# NodeJS, PassportJS: Adding another field for authentication

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm getting start with Node and Password and I want to modify the default authentication of passport slightly.
I want to add a nickname field to authentication in addition to usual username/email and password fields. This was how I modified:

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
    // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
    // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
    User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
        // if there are any errors, return the error
        if (err)
            return done(err);

        // check to see if theres already a user with that email
        if (user) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
        } else {

/////////////// MODIFIED PART ////////////////
                User.findOne({ 'local.nickname' :  req.body.nickname }, function(err, user) {
                    if (user) {
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That nickname is already taken.'));
/////////////////////////////////////////////
                    }
                });
...
...
```

But the program exits with :

> throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
>             ^ POST /signup Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. 302     at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:691:11)
>   72ms - 72b    at ServerResponse.res.setHeader
>   (/home/madu/Programming/NodeJS/easy-node-authentication-local/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:63:22)

```
at ServerResponse.res.set.res.header (/home/madu/Programming/NodeJS/easy-node-authentication-local/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:527:10)
at ServerResponse.res.location (/home/madu/Programming/NodeJS/easy-node-authentication-local/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:657:8)
at ServerResponse.res.redirect (/home/madu/Programming/NodeJS/easy-node-authentication-local/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:698:8)
at allFailed (/home/madu/Programming/NodeJS/easy-node-authentication-local/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:124:20)
at attempt (/home/madu/Programming/NodeJS/easy-node-authentication-local/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:231:28)
at Context.delegate.fail (/home/madu/Programming/NodeJS/easy-node-authentication-local/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:226:9)
at Context.actions.fail (/home/madu/Programming/NodeJS/easy-node-authentication-local/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/context/http/actions.js:35:22)
at verified (/home/madu/Programming/NodeJS/easy-node-authentication-local/node_modules/passport-local/lib/passport-local/strategy.js:82:30)
```

Process finished with exit code 8

I have two questions:

1. How to fix this issue -
2. Is this the desired way of doing this (authenticating on nickname after username)

Thank you.

Comment: Please, could you write the entire stack trace ?

Comment: Thank you vinz. I edited with the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `res.send` twice (or anything that send the headers). You could simply debug headers like that in express:

```
app.use(express.json()); // or anything
...
app.use(function(req, res, next)
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.on('header', function() {
    console.trace('HEADERS GOING TO BE WRITTEN');
  });
  next();
});
}
..
app.use(express.router);
```

see [Best way to debug 'Can't set headers after they are sent' error in Express / Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311137/best-way-to-debug-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-error-in-express-nod). Like so, you will be able to see what triggers the sending of the headers from the stacks.

That said, I use my, own route for user registration. Here is an adaptation (assuming the file is required and `create` is added into the router):

```
exports.create = function (req, res, next) {
    User.findOne({
        'local.email': req.body.email,
        'local.nickname': req.body.nickname
    }, function (err, user) {
        if (user) {
            req.flash('error', 'user already exists');
            return res.redirect('/signup'):
        }
        var user = new User(req.body);
        user.provider = 'local';
        user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.send(err);
            }

            // manually login the user once successfully signed up
            req.logIn(user, function (err) {
                if (err) return next(err);
                return res.redirect('/');
            });
        });
    });
};
```

You might also use schema validation . See https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo/blob/master/app/models/user.js

Example :

```
UserSchema.path('email').validate(function (email, fn) {
  var User = mongoose.model('User')
  if (this.doesNotRequireValidation()) fn(true)

  // Check only when it is a new user or when email field is modified
  if (this.isNew || this.isModified('email')) {
    User.find({ email: email }).exec(function (err, users) {
      fn(!err && users.length === 0)
    })
  } else fn(true)
}, 'Email already exists')
```

for the email. do the same for username.

Comment: Thank you vinz. I like how we can put both email and nickname in the findOne(), but I'd like to know individually whether a user with that email exists, or that nickname exists. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you vinz. But could you tell me how I can get rid of that error of sending response twice. Thank you.